# How do I calculate Return on Equity using moneycontrol data?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, stock-markets, equity

I am just starting with the stock market and I find the terms in books/tutorials not exactly matching with the balance sheet values. I am trying to calculate Return on equity= Net Income/Avg Shareholder Equity. Am I doing it correct

[[image: Profit Loss Screenshot]]

[[image: Equity Details Screenshot]]

Is the calculation 3330.10/Avg(21,597.57, 13,366.07) correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumptions. It looks like "Shareholder Equity" is reported as "Shareholder Funds" on the moneycontrol financial statements. I'm not sure if you are using moneycontrol for India-specific stocks but there are alternative sites that will provide more detailed financial statements.
I hope this answers your questions!

Comment: Shouldn't we use Total Shareholder's Funds instead of Total Reserves and Surplus?